# Getting error inside the class using PHP

Tags: php

I am facing the following error while accessing the variable inside the class using PHP.

> Error:
>       Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in /var/www/oditek.in/subhra/database.php on line 28
>       Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /var/www/oditek.in/subhra/database.php on line 28

I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'spesh');
/**
* 
*/
class DBOperations
{

    private $pdo;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }
    public function connect() {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_DATABASE.";charset=utf8mb4";
        $options = [
          PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // turn off emulation mode for "real" prepared statements
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //turn on errors in the form of exceptions
          PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, //make the default fetch be an associative array
        ];
        try {
          $this->$pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          error_log($e->getMessage());
          exit('Something weird happened'); //something a user can understand
        }
    }
    public function db_insert($table,$values, $columns=array()){
        if($table=="" || $values==""){
            return false;
        }
        $columnstr=$valuestr="";
        $valprepArr="";
        if(count($columns)>0){
            $columnstr=implode(",", $columns);
            $columnstr="(".$columnstr.")";
        }
        foreach($values as $key=>$val){
            if($valuestr !=""){
                $valuestr.=",?";
            }else{
                $valuestr.="?";
            }
            array_push($valprepArr, $val);
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." ".$columnstr." VALUES (".$valuestr.")";
        $stmt = $this->$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($valprepArr);
        return $this->$pdo->lastInsertId();
        $stmt = null;
    }
}
?>
```

Here Inside the class file I am getting this error and I want to resolve this.

Comment: Its `$this->pdo` not `$this->$pdo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This row:

```
$this->$pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options);
```

should be:

```
 $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options);
```

And everywhere you use `$this->$pdo` should be `$this->pdo`

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in
>   /var/www/oditek.in/subhra/database.php on line 28

**solution**: On line 28 `$this->$pdo` should be `$this->pdo`

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
>   /var/www/oditek.in/subhra/database.php on line 28

After `$this` there need to be called a property or method or function defined in class or where `$this` object is created.